# Empirical conditional density of continuous variables

Tags: sampling, multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability, density-estimation, multivariate-distribution

I have a dataframe, with data of several continuous variables. The variables are not independent.

My goal is to sample from the distribution that generated this data.

What's a relatively easy and practical way to do this?

One quick and dirty approach I can think of is to discretize all variables and then sample from the buckets. Is this a decent approach? What's a better one?

A cleaner fix could be to do PCA and do the above approach on the principal components. However this is not ideal in my case due to user needs.

Comment: Why not just sample the rows of the dataframe randomly with replacement?

Comment: @Tim thanks, that's a good point. I am however also interested in sampling out of sample points, if possible. It will be great if there's a decent easy method to do this.